# Adding tables to list of tables with custom chapter breakdown

Tags: table-of-contents, etoolbox

Running the code below is supposed to modify my list of tables to show the Chapter number above each set of tables related to that chapter.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\preto\table{%
  \ifnum\value{table}=0\addtocontents{lot}{{\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}
```

However for some untold reason it is also adding the chapter number in sections where there are no tables. The output from running the code is show below:

```
Chapter 0
Chapter 0
Chapter 2
  2.1  Table name                                 page number
  2.2  Table name                                 page number
Chapter 3
  3.1  Table name                                 page number
Chapter 6
```

Where there is no chapter 0 and chapter 6 is the last chapter. It displays the right number of tables from chapters 2 and 3 however I'm not sure why it also includes chapter 0 and 6 which have no tables.

I have found the cause of the issue which is a table in the title page and in the appendices. Is there anyway to modify the above `\preto` statement to ignore certain `\include` files?

Comment: And you compiled at least twice?

Comment: At least twice.

Comment: @MattStokes Somehow the code works fine for me, leaving aside a few spacing problems. I tried with six chapters, with tables only in two and three, just like you. Please consider posting your MWE which produces the problem for you.

Comment: I have made the necessary edits

Comment: I have found the cause of the issue which is a table in the title page and in the appendices. Is there anyway to modify the above \preto statement to ignore certain \include files?

Comment: There's got to be a better way than that. Can you copy either of my MWEs and show what table in the title page or appendices is causing problems? I can't imagine why you'd need a table (floating environment) on a title page. A `tabular` environment? Maybe. But not a table.

Answer (score 1):

Like @MMA, I can't reproduce the symptom with the following MWE (and all but the first chapter heading in the LoT is indented incorrectly). Please see what the difference is between your document and this one to narrow down where the problem occurs:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\preto\table{%
  \ifnum\value{table}=0\addtocontents{lot}{{\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\chapter{This chapter has no tables}
\chapter{This chapter also has no tables}
\chapter{This chapter has tables}
\begin{table} \caption{Some caption} \begin{tabular}{l}0\end{tabular} \end{table}
\begin{table} \caption{Some other caption} \begin{tabular}{l}0\end{tabular} \end{table}
\chapter{Yet another table-free chapter}
\chapter{Followed by another chapter with tables}
\begin{table} \caption{Third caption} \begin{tabular}{l}0\end{tabular} \end{table}
\begin{table} \caption{Fourth caption} \begin{tabular}{l}0\end{tabular} \end{table}
\chapter{Third chapter with tables}
\begin{table} \caption{Fifth caption} \begin{tabular}{l}0\end{tabular} \end{table}
\begin{table} \caption{Sixth caption} \begin{tabular}{l}0\end{tabular} \end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

And working from your edited example, I had to clean up a few things to make it compile, but I still can't reproduce the symptom. There must be something else causing the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
% appendix, tocloft, etoolbox, titlesec, amsmath, and smartref appear to be irrelevant.
% Commented or not, the LoT problem hasn't yet appeared.
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath} \numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\usepackage{smartref} \addtoreflist{chapter}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\preto\table{% Both these \preto commands appear to be irrelevant.
  \ifnum\value{table}=0\addtocontents{lot}{{\bfseries Chapter \thechapter\vskip10pt}}\fi
}
\preto\section{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip10pt}\fi
}

\begin{document}

%\begin{preliminary} % This environment is currently undefined.
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
%\end{preliminary}

\chapter{One} \chapter{Two}

\chapter{Three}
Here's a table.
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[ht]{|c|lr|c|} 
%c stands for centre, l for left, r for right; the | puts lines in between, and the hline puts a horizontal line in
\hline
$n$ & $\alpha$ &$n\alpha$ & $\beta$\\
\hline
1 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 5\\
\hline
2 & 0.3 & 0.6 & 4\\
\hline
3 & 0.7 & 2.1 & 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A random table \label{tab1}}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\chapter{Four} \chapter{Five} \chapter{Six}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have made the necessary edits

Comment: Still haven't been able to reproduce the error. I also had to modify your MWE slightly to get it to compile. Verify that the second MWE works as it does for me, and if so, start looking for other differences between it and your real document. Alternatively, start commenting out parts of your real document until the error goes away. Then we can narrow down the problem more easily.

Comment: I have found the cause of the issue which is a table in the title page and in the appendices. Is there anyway to modify the above \preto statement to ignore certain \include files?